# MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'ShardIterator' in params

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have been trying to use AWS kinesis. I am unable to get the data in json string format so that I can directly write it to the elasticsearch service of `AWS` and store it for later use.

**code :**

```
'use strict'
    var env = require('dotenv').config();
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    var awsEs = require('http-aws-es');
    let https = require('https');
    let accessKey = 'xxxxxxxx';
    let uri = 'xxxxxxx';
    let path = 'xxxx';
    var request = require('request');

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxx',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    });

    var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({apiVersion: '2013-12-02'});


    var iterator;
    var params1 = {
      ShardId: 'shardId-000000000001', /* required */
      ShardIteratorType: 'LATEST', /* required */
      StreamName: 'demo', /* required */

    };
    kinesis.getShardIterator(params1, function(err, data1) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else console.log(data1);           // successful response
    });

    var params = {
        ShardIterator: kinesis.ShardIterator, /* required */
        Limit: 5
    };


    var es = new elasticsearch.Client({
        hosts: 'https://search-kafkaes-tos2gmttttteyeyeyeye.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com',
        connectionClass: awsEs,
        amazonES: {
            region: 'us-east-1',
            accessKey: 'xxxxxx',
            secretKey: 'xxxxxx'
        }
    });


    var getJsonSentiment = function (query, callback) {
        get_sentiments(query, function (data) {
            callback(data)
        });
    }

    //exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        kinesis.getRecords(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Receive message error", err);
            } else if (data.Messages) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.Messages[0].Body)
                var finalOutput = null;
                var deleteParams = {
                    QueueUrl: queueURL,
                    ReceiptHandle: data.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle
                };
                var req = {
                    uri: 'https://wxxxxxxt',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': accessKey,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ 'documents': [{ 'id': '1', 'text': jsonData["text"] }] })
                }
                request(req, callback);
                function callback(error, response, body) {
                    console.log("here3");
                    var dataJ = JSON.parse(body);
                    console.log("---------"+dataJ["documents"][0]["score"]);
                    console.log("topic:"+jsonData["topic"])

                    es.index({
                        index: 'tweets',
                        type: 'tweets',
                        body: {
                            topic: jsonData["topic"],
                            text: jsonData["text"],
                            latitude: jsonData["latitude"],
                            longitude: jsonData["longitude"],
                            score: dataJ["documents"][0]["score"]
                        }
                    });
                }
```

**Error Log :**

```
Receive message error { MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'ShardIterator' in params
    at ParamValidator.fail (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:61:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validate (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:125:42)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at callNextListener (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at /Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:85:9
    at finish (/Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:320:7)
    at /Users/archit/Desktop/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:9
  message: 'Missing required key \'ShardIterator\' in params',
  code: 'MissingRequiredParameter',
  time: 2017-12-08T04:22:26.517Z }
{ ShardIterator: 'XXXXXxxxxx' }
```

I have been trying to use AWS kinesis. I am unable to get the data in json format so that I can directly write it to the elasticsearch service of AWS and store it for later use.